# Rendering a form as a multi step Wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, wizard

I have a form that i am rendering as a 5 step wizard using [fuelUX wizard](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/).

I would like to show the value they selected in the previous steps and a summary of all the values they selected in the final step.

One way i can think of is to use HTML5 storage and using javascript to populate.

What are the other ways to get the value from fields and populating on other fields?

Comment: Are the "steps" ajaxy? Or are you submitting a form at each step?

Comment: Its just one form. but rendered as multiple steps. The form is submitted in the final step.

Answer (score 0):

fuelUX is a JavaScript-based solution. There is a couple of options:

1. Render the wizard inside of a form (for_for or form_tag) and store user options in the fields, and then do a post upon clicking the "submit" button at the end
2. Using the following code to fire an AJAX call to save the current step of the wizard.

   $('#your_wizard').on('changed', function (e, data) {
     // $.post('/your/path/', { data: data, ... });
   });